# An "IQ puzzle" of lines

Tags: visual, english

Which of the options, A-D, should replace the question mark in order to complete the image below?

---

[image]

Comment: No knowledge required whatsoever other than trivial. Remember, this is an "IQ puzzle" ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct option is:

> **B**

Because:

> Extending the short red/purple lines allows us to form letters. (Purple is used where the letter cannot be traced by a single line.)
>
>  The given squares spell out **MATRI**, so we want an **X** for the final square to spell **MATRIX**, which is option B.
>  [image]

Comment: Faster than expected. Great job!

Comment: Gives another meaning to rot13(Cebterffvir Zngevk)!